# Able to delete files, Unable to copy or modify them - PHP

Tags: php, apache2

Using the following code I receive an error when trying to copy a file, or anything else I try to do with it. I am however able to use almost identical code to delete the file.

```
$file = "img1.jpg";

if (!copy($file, "img2.jpg")) {
  echo ("Error copying $file");
} else {
  echo ("Copied $file");
}
```

Delete Code:

```
if (!unlink($file)) {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
} else {
  echo ("Deleted $file");
}
```

Anyone know why it might be doing this?

Edit: Apache owns the files but seems to be unable to read or write them as per is_readable and is_writeable

Edit2: added second argument to the copy code. This was not the problem, just me making errors in posting this question.

Comment: copy from ..... **to**

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "img1.jpg";
$newFile = "img1_copy.jpg";

if (!copy($file, $newFile)) {
  echo ("Error copying $file");
} else {
  echo ("Copied $file");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

The function `copy()` requires 2 arguments.

Comment: Error in writing the question, not the error I was experiencing

Comment: `I receive an error when trying to copy a file` What is it then? Copy the whole `.php` file instead of the snippets so we can further assist you.

Comment: The only other way you could be having issues, is if the permissions for the directory isn't set correctly. Make sure the folders have 777 permissions.

Comment: I just answered the question. Took me all of a few hours to end up posting here, only to spend another minute finding my final problem. Didn't help that I had to switch from a recent version of mint that was doing something screwy with php7 to ubuntu 14 using php5 to get other stuff to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change all permissions manually for each file, so that www-data owns it, and www-data (the group) can read and write to it. Apache did something weird and while the apache user owned and could read and write to the file, the group www-data was unable to do either.